# Two level iteration not working in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components, loop, template, for

I have two level of iteration in LWC, and the second iteration is not displayed even if there  are contents in it :

```html
<template for:each={calendarCol} for:item="ccd">               
  <div 
    key={ccd.id}
    class="slds-col slds-medium-size_1-of-6 slds-large-size_1-of-6 slds-grid_vertical"
  >
    <div class="slds-grid slds-grid_vertical slds-grid_vertical-align-center slds-p-horizontal_x-small">
      <div
        aria-describedby="dayOfWeek"
        class="slds-p-top_x-small slds-text-body_small cardWith"
      >
        <div
          class="noTimeSlots"
          aria-label={ccd.title}
          style="height: 466px;"
        >
          <!-- <p class="slds-assistive-text" >Hmm...no availability on this date. Try selecting another date.</p>-->
          <p>{ccd.title}</p>

          <template for:each={ccd.slots} for:item="slot">   
            <div key={slot.key}>{slot.startTime} - {slot.endTime}</div>
          </template>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

Is it supported or not ? Am I missing something here?

In the js I can loop on the arrays :

```js
for (var y in this.calendarCol) {
  console.log('## with slots for index :',this.calendarCol[y]);      
  
  for (var z in this.calendarCol[y].slots) {
    console.log('## slot ',this.calendarCol[y].slots[z]);  
  }       
}
```

So for me, I can also loop on it in my html. Right?

Here is the JSON representation of my data :

```
[{"title":"FRI 1","id":0,"key":1,"slots":[{"key":1,"startTime":"2022-04-01T10:00:00.000Z","endTime":"2022-04-01T12:00:00.000Z"},{"key":2,"startTime":"2022-04-01T12:00:00.000Z","endTime":"2022-04-01T14:00:00.000Z"}]},{"title":"SAT 2","id":1,"key":2,"slots":[{"key":3,"startTime":"2022-04-02T08:00:00.000Z","endTime":"2022-04-02T10:00:00.000Z"}]},{"title":"SUN 3","id":2,"key":3,"slots":[]},{"title":"MON 4","id":3,"key":4,"slots":[{"key":4,"startTime":"2022-04-04T08:00:00.000Z","endTime":"2022-04-04T10:00:00.000Z"},{"key":5,"startTime":"2022-04-04T10:00:00.000Z","endTime":"2022-04-04T12:00:00.000Z"},{"key":6,"startTime":"2022-04-04T12:00:00.000Z","endTime":"2022-04-04T14:00:00.000Z"}]},{"title":"TUE 5","id":4,"key":5,"slots":[{"key":7,"startTime":"2022-04-05T08:00:00.000Z","endTime":"2022-04-05T10:00:00.000Z"},{"key":8,"startTime":"2022-04-05T10:00:00.000Z","endTime":"2022-04-05T12:00:00.000Z"},{"key":9,"startTime":"2022-04-05T12:00:00.000Z","endTime":"2022-04-05T14:00:00.000Z"}]},{"title":"WED 6","id":5,"key":6,"slots":[{"key":10,"startTime":"2022-04-06T08:00:00.000Z","endTime":"2022-04-06T10:00:00.000Z"},{"key":11,"startTime":"2022-04-06T10:00:00.000Z","endTime":"2022-04-06T12:00:00.000Z"},{"key":12,"startTime":"2022-04-06T12:00:00.000Z","endTime":"2022-04-06T14:00:00.000Z"}]}]
```

Comment: It's working for me... https://webcomponents.dev/edit/0ZNFUBRrmBsDvGO4XQ9M/src/app.html?p=stories ... maybe your data is wrong?

Comment: Well... Can you just JSON.stringify and show us what the data looks like? FYI, for..in loops work on objects and arrays, so there's no guarantee you have an array. In fact, you should avoid using for..in for Arrays, and rather use for..of instead.

Comment: I edited the question to post the json. Thanks in anticipation

Comment: Thanks to @sfdcfox for providing a working example, modifying it to add your JSON is also working. It must happen something outside of what you described that prevent this to work. For example the way you get / use the JSON. Could you give us the js part of the component ?

Comment: @vanessen I've updated my example from the above link. It's still working as expected. Try comparing what you have in your code with this and see if there's some minor mistake somewhere.